# Why MyBatis SELECT is slower than JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mybatis

For an easiest query.

My JDBC code is like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT videos.id, videos.connector_id, videos.season_number FROM videos WHERE videos.connector_type = 'show';";
System.out.println("Create statement...");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    int input = scanner.nextInt();
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
    System.out.println("Time 1: " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start));
}
```

And MyBatis code is like this:

```
<select id="queryTest" resultType="map">
SELECT videos.id, videos.connector_id, videos.season_number FROM videos WHERE connector_type = 'show';
</select>

try (SqlSession session = DatabaseConnFactory.getSqlSession()) {
    start = System.nanoTime();
    maps = session.selectList("queryTest", parameterWrapper);
    System.out.println("Time 1: " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start));
}
```

Not considering the first query, for the following queries, JDBC always takes about 6ms~10ms, and MyBatis takes about 31~35ms, which is about 3 times.

For a more complex query (6 inner joins and an order by in it), JDBC only takes 25~30ms, while MyBatis needs 80~100ms.

I've tried to avoid using mapper, instead using session.selectList, session.select and session.selectCursor, but none of them has obvious better performance than MaBatis.Mapper.

How can I improve the performance of MyBatis?

Comment: In the example above there are two different SQL requests. Have you also tried to compare the same requests?

Comment: I tried SELECT videos.id, videos.connector_id, videos.season_number FROM videos WHERE connector_type = 'show'; in JDBC, it only takes less than 10ms (exclude the first time query)

Answer (score 2):

Define a fetch size to your query as mentioned in below code:

```
<select id="queryTest" fetchSize="1000" resultType="map">
```

Default `fetch size in jdbc for oracle is 10` and in `sql developer it is 50` which makes it really slow if you have 1000s of records. So in that case you need to define a suitable fetch size as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you. It seems not so helpful for the above easy query, but for a complex query, it reduce time cost from 80~100ms to less than 75ms. But it is still much slower than JDBC.

Comment: well in any case you can always increase the fetch size and one more thing indexing your database table would also enhance the performance.

Comment: But the question is why there is a performance gap between JDBC and MyBatis?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't any if you feel your query is slow in general then probably do some indexing increase the number of constraints in your where clause and incase of above question if your query runs faster any elsewhere then do some performance tuning at set a correct fetchsize to make it faster. If `1000` is not suitable than make it `2000` and so on.